# Access report prints multiple pages when text box control source is using a multi-value field from a table

Tags: ms-access

The Access 2010 report i have has a text box that uses a multi-value field from a table for its control source. I know multi-value fields in tables are bad but its what i have to work with at the moment.

The problem i am having is that even though its only a two page report when i physically print it or do a print preview i get more then 2 pages. So if the multi-value field has (2) values i will get (4) pages total with the same information basically (2) copies.

How can i prevent the report from printing a copy for each value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I will answer my own question now that i have found a work around.

I found a work around that will let me print only the pages i want (ie the first two pages or one copy not several)

In my macro instead of using RunMenuCommand PrintObject that just prints the report.

I created a vba function

```
    Function cmdPrint()
        DoCmd.PrintOut acPages, 1, 2   //acPages, start_page, end_page
    End Function
```

and used this function from the macro using RunCode cmdPrint()

Now I only get one copy not several. Like I said its a work around but it works for me and i hope that it will help someone else someday with the same problem.